# Gesture app that can link directly to app shortcuts?

Tags: miui, gestures

For example, I can long hold Clock app to access "Set Timer" in MIUI14 on Nova Launcher. However, when using Vivid Navigation Gestures, clicking on "Shortcut" or "Activity" - I am unable to find the same shortcut. Is anyone able to guide me on how to do so?

Comment: Hi, please note that questions directly asking for app recommendations are off-topic. Instead, we prefer the asker to just state the underlying problem that they want to solve and not put any restriction for apps-only, so we'd appreciate it if you could [edit] the question, add some details, and/or remove the restriction. Otherwise, you might be interested in our sister site, [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour) instead.